# Is it possible to add types for facets in a dgraph schema?

Tags: dgraph

I have found that I need to specify predicate types as int in my schema or else numbers get stored as type `float`:

```
MyNumericalProperty: int @index(int) .
```

I have facets that are also numbers, and in the JSON returned from dgraph they appear like so:

```
"MyProperty|MyPropertyFacet":1.000000
```

Is there a way to add this to the schema as an int?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, facets are not first-class citizen. So you can't define it. If you have a good use case, maybe opening an issue to request this feature would be interesting.